# dGrid: Using DnD and Paginaiton together

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dojo, dom-events, dgrid

I am using Dgrid with pagination extension to display Data. For the same grid I have implemented grid's DnD. So I can move rows up and down and rearrange row index using it.

But now, as the number of rows have increased, the grid is divided into more than 5 pages. In this case, how can I move the rows from my 5th page to 1st page using DnD?

One possibility I see is by changing the page on hover of pagination bar at bottom. As per the [docs](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/doc/components/extensions/Pagination.md) there is one method called as **gotoPage** which switches the page programmatically. But, how to capture grid pagination hover event? And how to get page number on hover so that can be passed to **gotoPage** method above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using Dgrid [events](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v1.2.0/doc/usage/Working-with-Events.md) on dom nodes. So basically, we can attach event for pages like below

```
grid.on('.dgrid-footer .dgrid-pagination .dgrid-navigation .dgrid-page-link:mouseover',function(event){
var pageindex  = event.target.textContent.trim();
    if(!isNaN(pageindex)){
       grid.gotoPage(pageindex);
    }
})
```

This will give control to dragged page number and then you can handle the rest afterward.